# Joining table cells containing the same text vertically during Runtime in Fast Report 6

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I need to join the selection using **TfrxTableObject.JoinSelection** using a loop but I am missing the gap/shift/difference when doing so.
So far, I managed to join the first 2 cells but after that the aforementioned gap shifts everything.
Note: I know this is easy but I seem to be stuck.

Input:

| Title |
| --- |
| A |
| A |
| (null) |
| B |
| B |
| B |
| (null) |
| C |
| C |
| C |
| C |

Output:

| Title |
| --- |
| A |
| (null) |
| B |
| (null) |
| C |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no gap.

```
    var
     tb : frxtableobject1;
     i, total : integer;
     s, ls : string;
    begin
     tb := frxReport1.FindObject('tb') as tfrxtableobject;
     i := 0;
     total := 0;
     ls := '';
     repeat
      if i < 11 then s := tb.Cells[0,i].Text;
    
      if (s = ls) and (i < 12) then
      begin
       inc(total);
      end
      else
      begin
       if total > 0 then
         if ls <> '' then
          tb.JoinSelection(0,i-1-total,0,i-1);
       total := 0;
      end;
      ls := s;
      inc(i);
     until i > 12;
    end;
```